# C, Invalid write with valgrind and void* variable

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I want to assign a variable void* to an attribut void* from a structure. 
My struct :

```
struct data{
    int n;
    void * cl;
}typedef data;
```

Then, I have this function :

```
void f(void *cl, int n){
    struct data *data = malloc(sizeof(data));
    data->cl = cl; //"Invalid write of size 8" from valgrind
    data->n = n;
}
```

EDIT : "void *cl" is null, I don't know why (but not data)
And I call it like this :

```
f(args_f(2), 1);
```

About args_f :

```
struct st_args * args_f(int n)
    {
        struct st_args *args = malloc(sizeof(struct st_args));
        if (args == NULL)
            return NULL;

        args->n = n;
        return args;
    }
```

The struct st_args :

```
struct st_args{
    int n;
    }typedef st_args;
```

Inside my function f, when I try the assignement "data->cl = cl;", valgrind says "Invalid write of size 8" on this line. why is that ?

Comment: Not entirely a solution, but you should check if `data` is `NULL` after `malloc`.

Comment: I found that the argument of f "void * cl" is null, but not data

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(data));`  returns size of pointer (4/8 bytes - depends on system), you got size of declared `data` pointer. You should write `malloc(sizeof(struct data))` to allocate memory for data object.

Comment: Please don't lie. The code you provided doens't compile, so you couldn't possibly hve run it. Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. (See [mcve].)

Comment: It worked rafix07, I don't have anymore invalide write. Thanks

Comment: Or write `struct data *data = malloc(sizeof *data);` and you should also check that `data != NULL` to validate the allocation as you do for `args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem here: `struct st_args *args` is local, and you have `return`ed it, without allocating proper memory.

```
struct data *data = malloc(sizeof(data));
```

At this instance, `data` is a pointer, and `malloc` would have allocated 4 (or 8) bytes of memory. It should have been,

```
struct data *data = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

This would allocate (if available) the required memory and segfault would go away.

Additionally, you should check if `data` is `NULL` after `malloc`, if yes then handle the error the way you have done in `args_f` function.

This is the exact reason why we should be avoiding variable naming convention where user-defined data types and variable names can be same.
For that matter, when I have a `typedef`, I typically have `_t` suffix to it to avoid any confusion.

For example,

This

```
struct data{
    int n;
    void * cl;
}typedef data;
```

would be something like this in my code

```
typedef struct stData {
    int32_t i_N;
    void *p_cl;
} data_t;
```